# How to show a group is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to write down the elements of the Alternating Group $A_3$ and check that this group is cyclic.

I know that $A_3=${$id, (1,2,3), (1,3,2)$} but i'm not sure how to show that it is cyclic. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The order is $3$, which is a prime.

Comment: What's the definition of a cyclic group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sigma=(123)$. Then $\sigma^2=(132)$. Hence, $A_3=\{ 1, \sigma, \sigma^2 \}$, which means that $A_3$ is the cyclic group generated by $\sigma$.